# Rounding a time

Tags: powershell

My understanding is that this should round the time to 3 decimals for the seconds. However, while it doesn't produce any errors, it also doesn't round, producing output like **00:02:42.6180000**

```
$elapsedTime = [datetime]$endTime - [datetime]$startTime
$elapsedTime = '{0:HH:mm:s.fff}' -f $elapsedTime
```

FWIW, the start end end times are simply strings from a txt file, in the format 00:47:19.876, which is why I want to do the rounding. The source data is only provided to three decimals, so no reason to be outputting to seven.

EDIT 1:
Joey,
I just made a little test jig, that looks like this

```
$startTime = '00:47:19.876'
$endTime = '00:49:21.023'

$elapsedTime = [datetime]$endTime - [datetime]$startTime
$elapsedTime = '{0:HH:mm:s.fff}' -f $elapsedTime

$elapsedTime
```

And my output is 00:02:01.1470000. Running PS2.0 on Windows 7 if that makes any difference.

EDIT 2:
Just revised to

```
$elapsedTime = '{0:hh\:mm\:ss\.fff}' -f $elapsedTime
```

Same output, with no errors.

Comment: Actually, you should be getting an exception with that code. `HH` is not a valid format specifier for TimeSpan. Fixing the errors (see Mathias' comment) does not exhibit the problem you're indicating for me.

Comment: `'{0:hh\:mm\:ss\.fff}' -f $elapsedTime`

Comment: @joey, well it definitely works...

Comment: PetSerAl, I tried yours as well. Still no change in the output. I am half tempted to go the kludge route and just -replace '0000', ''

Comment: @Gordon i've just tried your code in Powershell 5.1 on Windows 10. Works perfectly. What if you try something like this: `"$($elapsedTime.Hours.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0')):$($elapsedTime.Minutes):$($elapsedTime.Seconds).$($elapsedTime.Milliseconds)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Running PS2.0 on Windows 7 if that makes any difference.

It makes a significant difference in this case.

From [the .NET version 4.0 documentation for `TimeSpan.ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ecy8h51(v=vs.100).aspx) (emphasis added):

> **Notes to Callers**
>   Support for formatting TimeSpan values ***was added in the .NET Framework version 4***. However, the ToString() method overload remains culture-insensitive. [...]

That's the reason PowerShell ignores all of your formatting attempts.

You'll have to concatenate the individual parts manually:

```
'{0}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}.{3:D3}' -f (24*$elapsedTime.Days + $elapsedTime.Hours),$elapsedTime.Minutes,$elapsedTime.Seconds,$elapsedTime.Milliseconds
```